# Speed up creation of numpy array from list

Tags: python, arrays, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a 33620x160 `pandas` `DataFrame` which has one column that contains lists of numbers. Each list entry in the `DataFrame` contains 30 elements.

```
df['dlrs_col']

0        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
1        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
2        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
3        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
4        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
5        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
6        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
7        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
8        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
9        [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
10       [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573...
```

I'm creating a 33620x30 array whose entries are the unlisted values from that single `DataFrame` column. I'm currently doing this as:

```
np.array(df['dlrs_col'].tolist(), dtype = 'float64')
```

This works just fine, but it takes a significant amount of time, especially when considering I do a similar calculation for 6 additional columns of lists. Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
In [140]: df
Out[140]:
                                          dlrs_col
0  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
1  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
2  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
3  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
4  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
5  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
6  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
7  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
8  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
9  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]

In [141]: df.dlrs_col.apply(pd.Series)
Out[141]:
          0         1        2
0  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
1  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
2  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
3  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
4  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
5  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
6  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
7  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
8  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573
9  0.048142  0.047021  0.04573

In [142]: df.dlrs_col.apply(pd.Series).values
Out[142]:
array([[ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ],
       [ 0.04814247,  0.04702114,  0.04573   ]])
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but in my quick testing this actually took nearly twice as long as my previous method.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dlrs_col':[
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573],
[0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]]})

print (df)
                                          dlrs_col
0  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
1  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
2  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
3  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
4  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
5  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
6  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]
7  [0.048142470608688, 0.047021138711858, 0.04573]

print (np.array(df['dlrs_col'].values.tolist(), dtype = 'float64'))
[[ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]
 [ 0.04814247  0.04702114  0.04573   ]]
```

**Timings**:

```
In [56]: %timeit (np.array(df['dlrs_col'].values.tolist(), dtype = 'float64'))
The slowest run took 9.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop

In [57]: %timeit (np.array(df['dlrs_col'].tolist(), dtype = 'float64'))
The slowest run took 9.33 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.4 µs per loop
```